# Oracle sql - Email Address Validation

Tags: regex, email

All , i have the below query in my applicaton which i use to check for valid and invalid email addresses. The input string can contain multiple emails addresses saperated by a semi colon ';'.
The regular expression covers most of the valid emails untill someone pointed me towards the wiki link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address ) where the list of valid emails are showing as invalid in my query . Bascially from my observation from the list what i do see is that any set of characters enclosed in double quotes ' " ' is considered a valid email address which includes characters like @ and ; also (copied the list below). Also , DNS name (.com or any other) are also not mandatory as per wiki.

Can someone please help me come up with a regular expression or any other approach to include all valid cases.

```
WITH EMAIL_ADDRESS AS  
(SELECT NVL(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('a@b.com;@n.com', '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)), ' ') EMAIL_ID  
    FROM DUAL  
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(RTRIM('a@b.com;@n.com', ';'), ';') + 1)  
SELECT EMAIL_ID,  
       (CASE  
        WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(LOWER(EMAIL_ID),  
        '^[[:alnum:]'']+((\&|\.|\+|\-|_)[[:alnum:]'']+)?+@[[:alnum:]-]+((\.[a-z]{2,}){1,4})$') = 1 THEN  
         'Y'  
        ELSE  
         'N'  
       END) IS_VALID_EMAIL  
  FROM EMAIL_ADDRESS;  

EMAIL_ID       I  
--------------      -  
a@b.com        Y  
@n.com         N
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)